# Aggregation of Metrics by label

Tags: monitoring, prometheus

Currently, I am trying to write a service that reads information from prometheus, processes this and then exposes this information back to be scrape by prometheus.

I have this working, and the metrics are being **scraped**, but to process the metrics, I am using a queue to distribute work to consumers, this is cauing the metrics when queried to be (correctly) registered as multiple different timeseries due to the different instance labels.

From what I can see there seems to be two main options I know of but am unsure of one of them.

1. Add these metrics back to a queue and deploy a service to manage if these metrics continue to be exposed (this can be seen working by deploying only 1 instance of the app).
2. I believe that there may be a mechansim (the prometheus rules) to automatically consume these metrics and produce a single timeseries for each pod_name label, but i am unsure how to achieve this as I don't believe using sum(x) by (pod_name) is correct, as i do not with to have a sum of these values but a new series. If this is possible my other worry is then the redundant data once this new timeseries is created.

I appraciate any input
Kind Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [relabel_config](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#relabel_config) to modify labels as you wish.

Regarding the design, I think you need to have 2 labels: 1 for the instance that his metric was **originally** collected from, and one for for the instance that it was delegated by.

Comment: Hello, i tried this and sadly altering the __address__ label also affects the address prometheus tries to scrape the target, I get the idea that i may be misusing prometheus for this and need to make a metric collection service